# Long-term Estonian visa from the US - Indian passport

Tags: usa, schengen, schengen-visas, estonia

I am an Indian citizen working in the US on an Employment Authorization Document (EAD) under STEM OPT after completing my master's. My student visa has expired but my EAD is valid and I am in legal status. I am planning to relocate to Estonia to work - I have a job offer. The Estonian consulate mentions that I need to have a valid US visa to apply. I understand this being the case for a short term Schengen visa application where I am returning to the US (done that a couple of times). But if I relocating to Estonia... I am not planning to return to the US.

Does anyone have experience of applying for a long-stay D visa for any Schengen country from the US as a non-US citizen without a valid visa? I cannot return to India to apply, since I still want to continue working in the US until my visa is approved.

Any thoughts appreciated.

Comment: Usually it's enough to have proof that you're legally resident.  Did the Estonian consulate explicitly tell you that the EAD is insufficient?

Comment: I have asked them and am awaiting a response. But the documents list does not mention the EAD card being accepted. So I am not sure how it works in practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Estonian Consulate in New York explains](https://newyork.mfa.ee/long-stay-d-visa/#4) what documents are acceptable:

> applicants who aren’t US citizens, but reside in US: valid US residence permit or resident visa type A, E, F, G, H, I, J, L, O, R. F visa holders must present together with visa also the form I-20 with valid travel endorsement.  J visa holders must additionally present form DS-2019 (J1) with valid travel endorsement. Attention! Green card, visa and additional forms must be presented in original together with a copy.

Comment: Basically, they need to see that you reside in US legally.

Comment: I saw that but above on the same page it mentions:

"Citizens and residents of US. Resident status can be confirmed either by valid US residence permit (Green Card) or valid resident visa type A, E, F (with form I-20), G, H, I, J (with form J1) , L, O, R. The US residence permit or visa should be valid at least three months beyond the intended departure from Schengen area"

So it seems to apply either a green card or a valid visa. If as long as they don't need evidence of re-admissibility into the US for a long stay visa hopefully an EAD should work